# How do I join multiple strings?

Tags: python

How do I join all the strings in a stringList into one without printing it?

For example,

```
s = joinStrings([’very’, ’hot’, ’day’]) # returns string 
print(s)                                # Veryhotday
```

[image: here is the actual problem my professor gave me]

Comment: Strings already have a method that does this. `''.join([’very’, ’hot’, ’day’])`. just use that.

Comment: For questions regarding tertiary-level Python assignment problems, you may want to try **reading** the relevant documentation / paying attention in course. This is one of the first things you should learn in Python, and is easily found on Google.

Answer (score 16):

it feels a little backwards, but you join with a chosen uhh seperator
`''.join(['your','list','here'])`
you can fill in the `''` and it will use what ever is inside between each pair of items i.e `'---'.join(['your','list','here'])` will produce `your---list---here`

Answer (score 6):

You can solve it using single line for loop.

```
def joinStrings(stringList):
    return ''.join(string for string in stringList)
```

Everything is described in Python Documentation:
[Python Docs](https://www.python.org/doc/)

E.g.: String join method: 
[Python string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I am only learning python 2.7 so this probably won't help:

```
def joinStrings(stringList):
    list=""
    for e in stringList:
        list = list + e
    return list

s = ['very', 'hot', 'day']
print joinStrings(s)
```

Comment: This helped me as it allowed to add a period (.) at the end of each string.

Answer (score -1):

All the above solution are good...
You can also use extend(object) function...

```
String1.extend(["very", "hot", "day"] )
```

Enjoy....