# Concatenating trigrams from a tuple in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, arraylist, tuples, concatenation

Ok, so I am working on an assignment for a course in my linguistics BA where we are working with python to process texts. This is what I needed to do:

> Create a script that counts trigrams frequencies
>
> - Do not add dummy tokens
> - Lowercase every token and concatenate trigram units with an
>     underscore
> - What are the missing values in the output box?
> - Bonus: Try to solve the task by storing trigrams a tuples in the
>     dictionary

This is how I solved most if it:

```
lyrics = "Do you remember 21st night of September ? Love was changing the mind of pretenders While chasing the clouds away Our hearts were ringing In the key that our souls were singing As we danced in the night Remember how the stars stole the night away yeah yeah yeah Hey hey hey Ba de ya say do you remember ? Ba de ya dancing in September Ba de ya never was a cloudy day Ba duda ba duda ba duda badu Ba duda badu ba duda badu Ba duda badu ba duda yeah My thoughts are with you Holding hands with your heart to see you Only blue talk and love Remember how we knew love was here to stay Now December Found the love we shared in September Only blue talk and love Remember the true love we share today Hey hey hey Ba de ya say do you remember ? Ba de ya dancing in September Ba de ya never was a cloudy day There was a Ba de ya say do you remember ? Ba de ya dancing in September Ba de ya golden dreams were shiny days Now our bell was ringing aha Our souls was singing Do you remember every cloudy day yau There was a Ba de ya say do you remember ? Ba de ya dancing in September Ba de ya never was a cloudy day There was a Ba de ya say do you remember ? Ba de ya dancing in September Ba de ya golden dreams were shiny days Ba de ya de ya de ya Ba de ya de ya de ya Ba de ya de ya de ya de ya Ba de ya de ya de ya Ba de ya de ya de ya Ba de ya de ya de ya de ya"

lyric = lyrics.lower()
listText = lyric.split(" ")
freq = {}



while len(listText) > 2:
    trigram = (listText[0], listText[1], listText[2])
    if trigram in freq.keys():
        freq[trigram] += 1
    else:
        freq[trigram] = 1
    listText.pop(0)

sorted_data = sorted(freq.items() , key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True) 

for entry in sorted_data:
    print(str(entry[0])+"\t"+str(entry[1]))
```

The only part I am missing is to concatenate the trigram units with an underscore. It's supposed to be so simple, but I can't for the life of me find out how to make it happen. The output is supposed to be the concatenated trigrams followed by the frequency of said trigram. The teacher said it can be solved so easily, but I can't figure it out. Which is funny, because everything else I did here was super quick and easy (relatively).

I have tried many things, but for some reason, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string's [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) method. All you have to do is call a `'_'.join` on the tuple of trigrams when you print.

```
print(str('_'.join(entry[0]))+"\t"+str(entry[1]))
```

Other notes:

(1) You can be more pythonic and generate your `listText` using list comprehension like this: `listText = [word.lower() for word in lyrics.split()]`

(2)You can use `setdefault` of a dictionary instead of the `if/else` to increment/initialize the trigram like this: `freq.setdefault(trigram, 0)` and then increment `freq[trigram] += 1` without using any if/else block. Right now you are iterating through `freq.keys()` searching for `trigram` in your `if` statement, which is constant in time in Python 3 (equivalent to saying `trigram in freq`) but linear in time in Python 2.

Comment: Wow. It really was that simple.. haha! Thank you for the response. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if its just a matter of contacting them you can use `str.join`

```
trigram = (listText[0], listText[1], listText[2])
c_trigram = '_'.join(*trigram)
```

you can see a shameless self plugging example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149579/how-do-i-join-multiple-strings/42149618#42149618)