# Printing numbers after another without adding them together Python

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and I want to convert one of my codes to this language.
I have a little problem what I can't solve. My script have to make random numbers and printing them after another without adding them together.

```
time = random.randint(1000000000,9999999999)
no_hash = time+random.randint(1,100)+random.randint(1,10000)+random.randint(1,10000000)
```

Example output
4245200583 but I need just like this: 423694030332415251234.
As you see the code adding the numbers together (because of + between them) but I don't want to add the numbers together just print them.

Comment: cast to string, append to string?

Comment: In what languages would you expect this to work?

Comment: In Python I want to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your values is an `int`, so `+` will implement integer addition. You need to convert each `int` to a `str` first.

You can do that implicitly with various string-formatting operations, such as

```
time = random.randint(1000000000,9999999999)
no_hash = f'{time}{random.randint(1,100)}{random.randint(1,10000)}{random.randint(1,10000000)}'
```

or explicitly to be joined using `''.join`:

```
time = random.randint(1000000000,9999999999)
no_hash = ''.join([str(x) for x in [time, random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1,10000), random.randint(1,1000000)]])
```

Answer (score 0):

use `str()` to concatenate the numbers

```
time = random.randint(1000000000,9999999999)
no_hash = str(time)+str(random.randint(1,100))+str(random.randint(1,10000))+str(random.randint(1,10000000))
```

Comment: Repeated concatenation with `+` is probably the worst way to join multiple values into a single string.

Comment: @TheMineSlash this method can also be used:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42149618/14719340

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a type of integer, when you need to add a type of string.

use the str() declaration to make sure Python sees it as string.

For example:

```
time = random.randint(1000000000,9999999999)
no_hash = str(time)+str(random.randint(1,100))+str(random.randint(1,10000))+str(random.randint(1,10000000))
```